# android app run at start up and in background

Tags: android

im new to android, i made an application and i want it to run at start up automatically
and in the background for sure, can anybody help me with this????
regards

for example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    int delay = 10000;// in ms 

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
       public void run() { 
           AudioManager audio=((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE));
            audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        }
     }, delay);
```

}

i want this code to run at startup and in background

Answer (score 1):

Listen for this [broadcast Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) with a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and tell the system about it with a [Android Manifest receiver](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html).

Comment: dan - good answer, because its correct, but you could offer a bit more detail for a beginner.

Comment: exactly im new so if u can provide me with a small example for a code that for example show a hello world dialog when i start up the mobile, i need this plz, thx in advance

Comment: and im using emulator, i dont have device yet, so idk if i can test it on it or not

Comment: The emulator will be able to do this. I'm reluctant to give code out show me what you've tried based on the documents I referenced above and we can go from there.

Comment: my goal now is to turn the mobile to Silent Mode when i start it up, this is not my idea but if i were able to do this, so i can continue to my graduation project, so here is the code that i want it to be executed when the mobile starts up and keep running in the background

Comment: int delay = 10000;// in ms 

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        timer.schedule( new TimerTask(){
           public void run() { 
            AudioManager audio=((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE));
    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
            }
         }, delay);

Comment: You can edit the original question to put code, but you're just restating what you already know, try using what you learned from the articles I posted.

Comment: ok Done i made it thxxxxx, i have another question, while the program is running in background, if i pressed the icon of the program it will start another process again, i want it to bring the running process if there is to screen not start another one!! can u help with that? regards

Comment: Write up a new question and I'll respond there.

Comment: ok here is it   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355783/bring-running-process-to-foreground

Answer (score 0):

If you want anything run in background then you should take the help of services not activity.

Comment: can u provide me with a small example ? a working example so i can understand the idea please?