# bring running process to foreground or disable multiple instances of application

Tags: android, android-emulator

im new to android

i have an application that running in the background
using moveTaskToBack(true); method

the problem is if user clicked on the application icon
it will run another process, not just bring the running one to foreground

how can i solve this???

Example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

int delay = 10000;// in ms
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
AudioManager audio = ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE));
    audio.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
moveTaskToBack(true);
}, delay);
}
```

i tried this

```
<activity android:name=".LaunchActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    >
lanchmode=singleinstance
```

but it didnt work!!

any help?

Answer (score 0):

To make the activity not have multiple instances use the activity [launchMode parameter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in your Manifest. Set it to `singleInstance` or `singleTask`.

Comment: can u tell me what exactly i should write in the mainfest??

Comment: Are you using Eclipse with ADT or exiting the xml directly?

Comment: i added the parameter but nth changed!!.....  <activity android:name=".LaunchActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:launchMode="singleInstance"
  >

Comment: You set it correctly, what may be happening is the activity is being destroyed and restarted.  If you want true backgrounding you'll have to use a Service as the system can kill any Activity in the background.

Comment: no the activity is still running, i knew coz the code is setting three timers 10sec 20 sec 30 sec, the first timer turn the mobile to silent mode and the second turn it to vibration and the last to normal, so i can notice the status bar that it still running and when i try to run another process i can see that both are running!!

Comment: The timer is running in a different thread, not in the Activity. When you reopen the Activity is recreated, that's why you're seeing two countdowns, check logcat to see that they have the same pid and you'll see that they are in the same process.

Comment: i think ya you are right!! what to do?? i simply want when i press home button the app go to background and when i click on its icon it come back to forground, what can i do???

Comment: Check out the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle). You'll have to hold this state outside of the activity. Create your own custom application class to hold this business logic as part of your model.

Comment: can you please check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366631/action-screen-on-action-screen-off-not-working